# CSS image thumbnail roll-over to display text

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position, rollover

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: rollover]

STEP logo is a thumbnail, and the RV logo next to it is the same, except it is being hovered on, at this point VIEW PROJECT and a blue see-through background appear.

I tried a few things:

Making the img a background of an `<a>` tag and placing a `<p>` tag in the `<a>` tag and using `display: none;` and then on `:hover` changing to `display: block;`

This layout is responsive so that caused problems, my code was something like this:

HTML:

```
<a class="work-thumb" href="#"><p class="work-thumb-rollover">view project</p></a>
```

CSS:

```
a.work-thumb {
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    background-image: url(images/work1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
    background-position: center;
}
    /* This code works, the image as the background is responsive */

p.work-thumb-rollover {
    display: none;
}

p.work-thumb-rollover:hover {
    display: block;
    text-align: centre;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
}

    /* This doesn't seem to work, the width 100% doesn't take the width of it's parent and on rollover no color appears? */
```

I also tried using the img tag in HTML and Absolute Positioning:

HTML:

```
<a class="work-thumb" href="#"><img src="images/work1.jpg" alt="work"><p class="work-thumb-rollover">view project</p></a>
```

CSS:

```
.work-thumb {
    position: relative;
}

.work-thumb img {
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

p.work-thumb-rollover {
    display: none;
}

p.work-thumb-rollover:hover {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: centre;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;        
}
```

This one, the P tag width wouldn't take that of it's parent, and would stick to the top right of the box (no matter what `top` or `left` attributes i gave it).

I tried things similar to this, i've deleted them and gone back to square one (of just having the images in the html with no CSS apart from the responsiveness at the minute) but I tried variations on these and just could not get them to work.

Can any one shine any light on this, or provide an easy solution they may have already used or seen?

Comment: The images of the 'work thumbnails' is not my work, just for the record. I just screen shotted it from a site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just with CSS/3 and HTML:

[Heres an example I made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/7Db9n/)

You'd have to replace the

```
 background-color
```

with

```
 background-image
```

to get the result youre after.

EDIT: **Heres an updated JSFiddle**  [Link >>](http://jsfiddle.net/7Db9n/2/)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look - This is almost what I am after, except I want to still be able to see the original background image on `hover`. Do you know how I could achieve that?

Comment: sure! just place the image in the div instead, and style it to make it centered http://jsfiddle.net/7Db9n/3/

Comment: You my friend, are awesome. Thank's a lot! I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

You may convert the anchor tag to a div with **specific width and height** and on **:hover** you can **change the background image**. the div must be styled

> display:inline-block

Comment: I cannot use a specific width and height, as the design is fluid, the widths are all calculated using percentages, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to show the text plus change the background image on hover. Why not use a little jquery to get it done:

```
<a class="work-thumb" href="#"><img src="images/work1.jpg" alt="work"><p class="work-thumb-rollover"></p></a>

$('.work-thumb').hover( function() {

$('.work-thumb-rollover').text('view project');
$('.work-thumb > img').attr('src', 'images/work2.jpg');

});
```

Comment: Almost, I would like the background image to remain the same through out, so in my picture, the RV would be just the image, then on hover, the 'VIEW PROJECT' and Magnifying glass are almost overlaid onto the background image, and disappear when you are not hovering again. Any ideas?